# motionEvent.ACTION_UP not called even when returning 'true' on ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android, touch, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I have a touch listener where the `ACTION_UP` is not called. I saw there are hundreds of questions where people are not able to get the `ACTION_UP` event. All of them have similar problem that they are not returning `true` on `ACTION_DOWN` event and that's why the `ACTION_UP` is not called. Well, I did the changes yet I am not able to see the `ACTION_UP` event.

Here is my very simple code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        Log.d(TAG,"down");
    }else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        Log.d(TAG,"up");
    }
    return true;
}
```

The `ACTION_DOWN` is called every time, as expected.
The `ACTION_UP` is called when I just tap the `view`, not if I swipe or scroll.

Comment: check for `ACTION_CANCEL` in that case: `The current gesture has been aborted. You will not receive any more points in it. You should treat this as an up event, but not perform any action that you normally would.`, BTW why dont you just call inside onTouch method: `Log.d(TAG, "onTouch " + event)`?

Comment: @pskink Yh you are right! But i dont understand why this is happening. Why getting cancled?

Comment: read `ViewGroup#onInterceptTouchEvent` documentation

Comment: I am also facing this case. it only happens for a swipe or scroll. 
did you find solution @SrujanBarai ?